# Blazor WASM on ASP.NET Core with Open Iddict gRPC unauthorized requests not working even with [AllowAnonymous]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, grpc, openiddict

I have blazor wasm app hosted on asp net core and connected by grpc-web. It works perfectly with authorized user but I cant make unauthorized grpc calls. I get this in logs:

```
OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore was forbidden.
```

But with authorized user this request works fine.

My startup.cs (tried in every possible order auth/grpc/route):

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(policy => policy
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithExposedHeaders("Grpc-Status", "Grpc-Message", "Grpc-Encoding", "Grpc-Accept-Encoding"));
            
app.UseGrpcWeb(new GrpcWebOptions { DefaultEnabled = true });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(options =>
{
    //options.MapGrpcServices(); //Here grpc

    options.MapRazorPages();
    options.MapControllers();
    options.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});
```

Mostly app configured from official sample: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Balosar

Adding `[AllowAnonymous]` on grpc service doesnt help.
How I can allow unauthorized requests for some grpc services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you migrated your gRPC solution from Identity Server 4 and have in Blazor.Client `Program.cs` something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClientName", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
   .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()))
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

Try to remove `.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>()` but dont forget test your app for correct auth requests!

In result you will have something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClientName", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
   .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
```